# Pasar un dato de un datagridview a otro datagriedview

Tags: c#

lo que quiero hacer es que al darle al boton de aceptar pase los datos seleccionados del checkbox al segundo datagrid view
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
using Parrot.Kitchen.App.Controller;
using Parrot.Kitchen.Business.Entities.Model;
using Parrot.Common.CustomComponent;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Parrot.Kitchen.App.Forms
{
    public partial class KitchenSetup : Form
    {
        private BizKitchenConfiguration bizKitchenConfiguration;
        private KitchenSetupController kitchenSetupController;
        private DataTable DataKitchenArea;
        private DataTable DataTableSection;
        private CustomDataGridView DataGridViewKitchenArea;
        private CustomDataGridView DataGridViewSectionArea;
        private CustomDataGridView DataGridViewSelectionArea;
        private MessageForm messageForm;
        private string TextMessage;
        private string KitchenAreaId;
        private string SectionAreaId;

        public KitchenSetup(BizKitchenConfiguration bizKitchenConfiguration)
        {
            this.bizKitchenConfiguration = bizKitchenConfiguration;
            this.kitchenSetupController = new KitchenSetupController(this.bizKitchenConfiguration.ConnectionIp);
            this.DataGridViewKitchenArea = new Parrot.Common.CustomComponent.CustomDataGridView();
            this.DataGridViewSectionArea = new Parrot.Common.CustomComponent.CustomDataGridView();
            this.DataGridViewSelectionArea = new Parrot.Common.CustomComponent.CustomDataGridView();
            this.TextMessage = String.Empty;
            this.AddDataGridView();
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void GetLicenceType()
        {
            if (this.bizKitchenConfiguration.ScreenId == -1)
            {

                this.bizKitchenConfiguration.TypeService = this.kitchenSetupController.GetLicenceType(
                    this.bizKitchenConfiguration.RestuarantId
                );
            }
            else 
            {
                this.bizKitchenConfiguration.TypeService = this.kitchenSetupController.GetKitchenParameter(
                    "Service_Type",
                    this.bizKitchenConfiguration.ScreenId
                );
            }

            if (this.bizKitchenConfiguration.TypeService.Equals("Food"))
            {
                this.ChkFoodService.Checked = true;
                this.DataGridViewKitchenArea.dataGridView.Visible = true;
                this.DataGridViewSectionArea.dataGridView.Visible = true;
                this.LbSectionArea.Visible = true;
            }
            else if (this.bizKitchenConfiguration.TypeService.Equals("Quick"))
            {
                this.ChkQuickService.Checked = true;
                this.DataGridViewKitchenArea.dataGridView.Visible = true;
                this.DataGridViewSectionArea.dataGridView.Visible = false;
                this.LbSectionArea.Visible = false;

            }
        }

        private void LoadConfigDataKitchenArea()
        {
            this.DataKitchenArea = new DataTable();
            this.DataKitchenArea.Columns.Add("Sel", typeof(bool));
            this.DataKitchenArea.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(int));
            this.DataKitchenArea.Columns.Add("Nombre", typeof(string));
        }

        private void LoadConfigDataTableSection()
        {
            this.DataTableSection = new DataTable();
            this.DataTableSection.Columns.Add("Sel", typeof(bool));
            this.DataTableSection.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(int));
            this.DataTableSection.Columns.Add("Nombre", typeof(string));
        }

        private void GetScreenId() 
        {
            string result = String.Empty;
            result = this.kitchenSetupController.GetScreenId();
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(result))
            {
                this.bizKitchenConfiguration.ScreenId = Int32.Parse(result);
                this.TxtKitchenId.Text = result;
            }
            else 
            {
                int id = this.kitchenSetupController.GetIdScreen();
                this.bizKitchenConfiguration.ScreenId = -1;
                this.TxtKitchenId.Text = (id + 1).ToString();
            }
        }

        private void GetKitchenArea() 
        {
            List<BizKitchenArea> bizKitchenAreaList = this.kitchenSetupController.GetKitchenArea(
                    this.bizKitchenConfiguration.RestuarantId
                );
            if (bizKitchenAreaList != null && bizKitchenAreaList.Count >= 1) 
            {
                this.LoadConfigDataKitchenArea();
                foreach (BizKitchenArea kitchenArea in bizKitchenAreaList)
                {
                    DataRow dr = this.DataKitchenArea.NewRow();
                    dr["Sel"] = false;
                    dr["Id"] = kitchenArea.Id;
                    dr["Nombre"] = kitchenArea.KitchenAreaName;
                    this.DataKitchenArea.Rows.Add(dr);
                }
                this.DataGridViewKitchenArea.BindDataGridView(this.DataKitchenArea);
                this.DataGridViewKitchenArea.AddHeaderCheckBox();

            }
        }

        private void GetTableSection()
        {
            List<BizTableSection> bizTableSection = this.kitchenSetupController.GetTableSection(
                    this.bizKitchenConfiguration.RestuarantId
                );
            if (bizTableSection != null && bizTableSection.Count >= 1)
            {
                this.LoadConfigDataTableSection();
                foreach (BizTableSection tableSection in bizTableSection)
                {
                    DataRow dr = this.DataTableSection.NewRow();
                    dr["Sel"] = false;
                    dr["Id"] = tableSection.Id;
                    dr["Nombre"] = tableSection.SectionName;
                    this.DataTableSection.Rows.Add(dr);
                }
                this.DataGridViewSectionArea.BindDataGridView(this.DataTableSection);
                this.DataGridViewSectionArea.AddHeaderCheckBox();
                this.DataGridViewSectionArea.dataGridView.Columns["Nombre"].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
            }
        }

        private void AddDataGridView() 
        {
            // 
            // DataGridViewKitchenArea
            // 
            this.DataGridViewKitchenArea.dataGridView.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(38, 177);
            this.DataGridViewKitchenArea.dataGridView.Name = "DataGridViewKitchenArea";
            this.DataGridViewKitchenArea.dataGridView.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(250, 130);
            //
            // DataGridViewSectionArea
            // 
            this.DataGridViewSectionArea.dataGridView.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(28, 400);
            this.DataGridViewSectionArea.dataGridView.Name = "DataGridViewSectionArea";
            this.DataGridViewSectionArea.dataGridView.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(250, 108);
            //
            // DataGridViewSelectionArea
            //
            this.DataGridViewSelectionArea.dataGridView.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(80, 800);
            this.DataGridViewSelectionArea.dataGridView.Name = "DataGridViewSelectionArea";
            this.DataGridViewSelectionArea.dataGridView.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(500, 220);


            this.Controls.Add(this.DataGridViewSectionArea.dataGridView);
            this.Controls.Add(this.DataGridViewKitchenArea.dataGridView);
        }

        private void GetSelectedId()
        {
            this.KitchenAreaId = String.Empty;
            this.SectionAreaId = String.Empty;
            if (this.DataGridViewKitchenArea.dataGridView.RowCount > 0)
            {
                foreach (DataGridViewRow row in this.DataGridViewKitchenArea.dataGridView.Rows)
                {
                    if (Boolean.Parse(row.Cells["Sel"].Value.ToString()))
                    {
                        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(this.KitchenAreaId))
                        {
                            this.KitchenAreaId += row.Cells["Id"].Value.ToString();
                        }
                        else 
                        {
                            this.KitchenAreaId += "," + row.Cells["Id"].Value.ToString();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            if (this.DataGridViewSectionArea.dataGridView.RowCount > 0)
            {
                foreach (DataGridViewRow row in this.DataGridViewSectionArea.dataGridView.Rows)
                {
                    if (Boolean.Parse(row.Cells["Sel"].Value.ToString()))
                    {
                        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(this.SectionAreaId))
                        {
                            this.SectionAreaId += row.Cells["Nombre"].Value.ToString();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            this.SectionAreaId += "," + row.Cells["Nombre"].Value.ToString();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private void SaveKitchenSetUp() 
        {
            int screenId;
            try
            {
                this.GetSelectedId();
                bool result = Int32.TryParse(TxtKitchenId.Text, out screenId);
                if (result)
                {
                    if (this.bizKitchenConfiguration.ScreenId == -1)
                    {
                        this.kitchenSetupController.SaveKitchenSetUp(
                                screenId,
                                this.KitchenAreaId,
                                this.SectionAreaId,
                                1
                            );
                        this.bizKitchenConfiguration.ScreenId = screenId;
                        this.bizKitchenConfiguration.KitchenAreaId = this.KitchenAreaId;
                        this.bizKitchenConfiguration.SectionAreaId = this.SectionAreaId;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        this.kitchenSetupController.SaveKitchenSetUp(
                               screenId,
                               this.KitchenAreaId,
                               this.SectionAreaId,
                               2
                           );
                        this.bizKitchenConfiguration.ScreenId = screenId;
                        this.bizKitchenConfiguration.KitchenAreaId = this.KitchenAreaId;
                        this.bizKitchenConfiguration.SectionAreaId = this.SectionAreaId;
                    }
                    this.TextMessage = "La configuración de Kitchen fue guardada con éxito.";
                    this.ShowMessageForm();
                    this.Close();
                }
                else 
                {
                    this.TextMessage = "Hubo un error, porfavor intente de nuevo.";
                    this.ShowMessageForm();
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                this.TextMessage = "Hubo un error, porfavor intente de nuevo.";
                this.ShowMessageForm();
            }
        }

        private void ShowMessageForm()
        {
            this.messageForm = new MessageForm();
            this.messageForm.Owner = this;
            this.messageForm.TextMessage = this.TextMessage;
            this.messageForm.ShowDialog();
            this.messageForm.Dispose();
        }

        private void SelectDataGridView() 
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(this.bizKitchenConfiguration.KitchenAreaId)) 
            {
                var kitchenAreaId = this.bizKitchenConfiguration.KitchenAreaId.Split(',');

                foreach (DataGridViewRow row in this.DataGridViewKitchenArea.dataGridView.Rows)
                {
                    foreach (var id in kitchenAreaId)
                    {
                        if (row.Cells["Id"].Value.ToString().Equals(id))
                        {
                             row.Cells["Sel"].Value = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(this.bizKitchenConfiguration.SectionAreaId))
            {
                var sectionAreaId = this.bizKitchenConfiguration.SectionAreaId.Split(',');

                foreach (DataGridViewRow row in this.DataGridViewSectionArea.dataGridView.Rows)
                {
                    foreach (var id in sectionAreaId)
                    {
                        if (row.Cells["Nombre"].Value.ToString().Equals(id))
                        {
                            row.Cells["Sel"].Value = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public BizKitchenConfiguration GetKitchenSetup() 
        {
            return this.bizKitchenConfiguration;
        }

        private void KitchenSetup_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (this.Owner.Owner != null)
            {
                this.Owner.Enabled = false;
                this.Owner.Visible = false;
                this.Location = new Point(
                    ((this.Owner.Owner.Width - this.Width) / 2),
                    ((this.Owner.Owner.Height - this.Height) / 2)
                );
            }
            else 
            {
                this.Owner.Enabled = false;
                this.Location = new Point(
                     ((this.Owner.Width - this.Width) / 2),
                     ((this.Owner.Height - this.Height) / 2)
                 ); 
            }
            this.TxtIpBd.Text = this.bizKitchenConfiguration.ConnectionIp;
            this.GetScreenId();
            this.GetKitchenArea();
            this.GetTableSection();
            this.GetLicenceType();
            this.SelectDataGridView();
        }

        private void KitchenSetup_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.Owner.Owner != null)
            {
                this.Owner.Enabled = true;
                this.Owner.Visible = true;
            }
            else 
            {
                this.Owner.Enabled = true;
            }
        }

        private void BtnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }

        private void BtnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.SaveKitchenSetUp();
        }

        private void btnAgregr_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void LbKitchenArea_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Intenta dejar sólo la porción de código relevante, te diría, que nadie va a leer todo tu código para buscar el problema..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para pasar la seleccion de un grid al otro segun tu codigo debes trabajar a nivel del `DataTable` o sea no con el control `DataGridView` de forma directa sino con los datos que asignas.

En el codigo veo que defines en la estructura del datatable el campo

```
this.DataKitchenArea.Columns.Add("Sel", typeof(bool));
```

con los cual si usas el `DataSource` del `DataGridView` entonces al cambiar la seleccion del checkbox se vera impactado el cambio en el `DataTable`
Entonces deberias iterar los datos

```
var rowsSelected = this.DataKitchenArea.AsEnumerable().Where(r=> Convert.ToBoolean(r["Sel"]));

foreach(DataRow rowOrigen in rowsSelected)
{
     DataRow rowDestino = this.DataTableSection.NewRow();
     rowDestino["Sel"] = rowOrigen ["Sel"];
     rowDestino["Id"] = rowOrigen["Id"] ;
     rowDestino["Nombre"] = rowOrigen["Nombre"];
     this.DataTableSection.Rows.Add(rowDestino);
}

this.DataGridViewSectionArea.BindDataGridView(this.DataTableSection);
```

para no tener que poner un `if` filtramos al principio solo los seleccionados con la ayuda de linq, lugo iteramos y creamos las nuevas rows en el datatable de seleccion, por ultimo asignamos nuevamente los datos para que los muestre actualizados

[Introducción (LINQ to DataSet)](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/getting-started-linq-to-dataset)

Comment: Hola, se mira muy bueno tu codigo, mi pregunta es de donde sale la variable dr que metes de parametro
`this.DataTableSection.Rows.Add(dr);`

Ya que en este parte me da error

Comment: En donde quiero que traiga los datos es al DataGridViewSelectionArea , El DatagridSectionArea ( poca diferencia ) es donde ya estan

Comment: disculpa olvide cambiar la variable, ya esta editado el codigo

Comment: Muy bueno funciona! una duda amigo, creo que es un bug ya que selecciono un par y me trae todo el grid y deja seleccionados, pero yo solo quiero que me traiga los seleccionados.
https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/225645/traer-solo-datos-con-checkbox-true?noredirect=1#comment419052_225645