# Traer solo datos con checkbox true

Tags: c#

Hola estoy pasando datos de un datagridview a otro y me los pasa pero al detectar un solo checkbox palomeado me trae todos y deja palomeado el que checkie, pero yo quiero que solo me traiga el que este palomeado y no todo su grupo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el codigo de mi boton de Agregar

```
  private void btnAgregr_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var rowsSelected = this.DataKitchenArea.AsEnumerable().Where(r => Convert.ToBoolean(r["Sel"]));
        foreach (DataRow rowOrigen in rowsSelected)
        {
            DataRow rowDestino = this.DataTableSection.NewRow();
            rowDestino["Sel"] = rowOrigen["Sel"];
            rowDestino["Id"] = rowOrigen["Id"];
            rowDestino["Nombre"] = rowOrigen["Nombre"];
            this.DataTableSection.Rows.Add(rowDestino);
        }
        this.DataGridViewSelectionArea.BindDataGridView(this.DataTableSection);
        }
```

Comment: no es rowselected.. es rowchecked ;)

Comment: Sigue pasando lo mismo

Comment: Pero vos no estas seleccionando la grilla.. estas seleccionando el data source.. y ese no tiene las marcas. las marcas, salvo que esta sea wpf y lo tengas bindeado, estan en la grilla...

Comment: al trabajar con los datos que aisgnaste al grid debes validar que cuando editas una celda esta impacte en la row del datatable, sino aplica el cambio en los datos entonces el linq no podra filtrar los marcados

Comment: Y eso como se hace, tendras un ejemplo

Comment: esto tiene que ver con el binding, no se bien que haces con el BindDataGridView(), pero deberias ver de asignar el DataSource del grid o usar el BindingSource https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-bind-objects-to-windows-forms-datagridview-controls

Comment: Esta bien raro por que despues de cargar todos los datos si me trae solo los datos que estan checkeados